# My pid identifier not expected

Tags: c, compilation, fork, pid

So for school I got this exercise where I need to make a program that calculates if a number is a prime number or not. This program should make use of parent and child processes, and strtoul should be used to convert the argv to a unsigned long.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void checkprime(unsigned long num);

int main(int argc, char *argv, char *env)
{       
strtoul(argv, NULL, 0);

pid_t pid = fork(); 

if(pid == 0)
{
    unsigned long number;

    printf("\nGive number to check: \n");
    scanf("%lu",&number);

    checkprime(number);
}
else if(pid < 0)
{
    perror("Fork Failed!");
}
else
{
    int status = -1, result;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    result = WEXITSTATUS(status);

    if(result == 1)
    {       
        printf("this is a prime number\n");
    }
    else if(status < 0)
    {
        perror("Something Failed");
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("this is not a prime number\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}

void checkprime(unsigned long num)
{
int i;
for(i = 2; i < num; i++)
{
    if(num % i == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
exit(1);
}
```

So when I try to compile this it says: line 13: identifier not expected. Error code 1.

The code on line 13 says: pid_t pid = fork();

Now my question is: Why do i get that error?

Its fixed, thanks everyone for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `pid_t = pid = fork();`? It's simply not valid C syntax.

Comment: What's worse, you *fixed* the error in the code you show here! You should always *copy-paste* the code, so you don't introduce other errors, or like in this case *fix* the error. Now this question is worthless since there is no problem.

Comment: im sorry i meant : pid_t pid = fork();

Comment: Check out http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html and move your call to `strtol(...)` below the declaration of your local variables.

Comment: there is a problem. i used pid_t pid = fork(); in the code i compiled. i just mistyped it when i tried to explain the error.

Comment: which local variables? the variables in the child process or the parent process?

Comment: You might have some weird character around that line. Delete lines 12~14, and rewrite the code, clean.

Comment: ah yeah it worked. thanks dude. ill remember that if something like this happens again.

Comment: The you seem to have an older compiler, that doesn't handle C99 (or later) where you could define variables anywhere. Pre-C99 you had to declare and define variables before any other statements in the current block.

Comment: Also, that should teach you to copy-paste the error as well. In full, complete, without modifications and as text.

Answer (score 2):

Some old versions of compilers accept [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89) (not [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))) as the default C dialect. You want C99 (since you have *a declaration* after a statement) at least.

If you use some old version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on some old Linux distribution, try compiling [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -g` where `-std=gnu99` sets the C dialect (you could also use `-std=c99` or better), `-Wall -Wextra` asks for warnings, `-g` wants debug information (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF), for the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)). Better yet, upgrade your GCC to a recent version (like [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) in November 2017) whose default is C11 with [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html).

Or put the declaration

```
pid_t pid= 0;
```

<sup>(I prefer to systematically initialize variables in C)</sup>

*before* the statements

```
 strtoul(argv, NULL, 0); //useless call, you need to store the result
 pid= fork();
```

Comment: Minor comment: in general, I'd suggest using `-std=gnu99` Instead of `-std=c99` to get C99 features unless you specifically want to avoid GNU extensions. Up to GCC 4.x the default for C compilation is `-std=gnu90`. Starting with GCC 5.x the default is `-std=gnu11` (skipping over `gnu99` and going right to the C 2011 standard with GNU extensions).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you it didn't expect to encounter an identifier `pid_t` at that line since the previous line wasn't an identifier.  You need to declare your variables at the top of the scope, and put other code below that.  You could either do this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv, char *env)
{       
    long int val=strtoul(argv, NULL, 0);
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    ...
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv, char *env)
{       
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    strtoul(argv, NULL, 0);
    ...
```

But you're missing the value returned from strtol

Answer (score 0):

You can use make shorter prime finder loop by changing, `i < num` to `i < num/2`.

This is one of standards for `main()` arguments:

> (int argc, char **argv)

Turn on gcc flag: `-Wall` to see all warnings in code.

As [@cleblanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813336/cleblanc) said in one of answer, store return value of `strtoul()` to a varibale `long int val = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);`.

we pass number for check, from command line arguments, 
`argv[1]` refers to number when we run program with

> ./prime 15

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void checkprime(unsigned long num);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 

    long int val = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);

    pid_t pid = fork(); 

    if(pid == 0){   
        checkprime(val);
    }
    else if(pid < 0){
        perror("Fork Failed!");
    }
    else{
        int status = -1, result;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        result = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        if(result == 1){       
            printf("Prime\n");
        }
        else if(status < 0){
            perror("Something Failed");
        }
        else{ 
            printf("Not prime\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void checkprime(unsigned long num)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < num/2; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

> Compile, Run

`gcc -Wall prime.c -o prime`

`./prime 15`

Comment: Code only (or code mostly) questions are off-topic. IMHO, a code only answer is frowned upon. You should add several sentences of explanation (in English)